# Did Gideon build two Altars in one night in Judges 6?

Tags: referent-identification, judges

(KJV) judges 6:24

> 24 Then Gideon built an altar there unto the LORD, and called it Jehovahshalom:  unto this day it is yet in Ophrah of the Abiezrites.

It seems in the above text Gideon built an altar were he offered unleavened cakes,but in the following text he seems to build another altar were he offered the bullock

(KJV) Judges 6:25

> 25 And it came to pass the same night, that the LORD said unto him, Take thy father's young bullock, even the second bullock of seven years old, and throw down the altar of Baal that thy father hath, and cut down the grove that is by it:  26 And build an altar unto the LORD thy God upon the top of this rock, in the ordered place, and take the second bullock, and offer a burnt sacrifice with the wood of the grove which thou shalt cut down.

Could this be two different altars or one & the same altar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the altars are in 2 different places, as noted in the verses themselves. The first was built in "Ophrah of the Abiezrites" (where Gideon had been before destroying Baal), and the second was built where Baal had been ("upon the top of this rock, in the ordered place").

Also, any readings of 6:28 imply that a second altar had been built.  See:

> Early the next morning, as the people of the town began to stir, someone discovered that the altar of Baal had been broken down and that the Asherah pole beside it had been cut down. **In their place a new altar had been built**, and on it were the remains of the bull that had been sacrificed. (NLT)
>
> In the morning when the people of the town got up, there was Baal's altar, demolished, with the Asherah pole beside it cut down and the second bull sacrificed **on the newly built altar**! (NIV)

Answer (score -1):

I examined a few commentaries and they didn't so much as mention the second altar. However, a plain reading of the text, especially prefaced as it is by "On the same night..." seems to make it plain that he built a second altar. This of course raises the question of why the second altar which would make a good follow up question!